# How do I make an action that mutates something and then opens another screen in react-admin?

Tags: react-admin

I'm building a front-end for an incident management system. One feature "approve", will create a new "workflow" object for the current incident, and then open an edit view on the newly created object.

It's easy enough to make an action that mutates an object (in this case creating the new workflow object), but I'm not clear on how I can make it so that the user is actually looking at that newly created object.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
const WorkflowButton = ({ data, label, ...props  }) => {
    const icon = props.icon;
    const current_state = data && data.workflow && data.workflow && data.workflow.workflow_state
    const valid_states = props.valid_states || []
    const current_state_is_valid = valid_states.includes(current_state)
    const payload = {
        data: {
            communication_id: data && data.id,
            workflow_state: props.workflow_state,
            data:"{}",
            author:get_current_user()
        }
    }

    const refresh_function = useRefresh()
    const [mutate_the_thing, { loading }] =
        useMutation({
        type: 'create',
        resource: 'workflows',
        payload: payload,
    });

    const mutate_and_refresh = ()=>{
        mutate_the_thing();
        refresh_function();
    }


    const disabled = loading || (! current_state_is_valid)
    return <Button label={label} onClick={mutate_and_refresh} disabled={disabled} icon={icon}/>;
};
```

Instead of refreshing the current view, I actually want to jump to a totally new view, the one that corresponds to the object that was just inserted. So how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use redirect(), there is an example in the documentation:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#handling-side-effects-in-other-hooks

```
import * as React from "react";
import { useMutation, useNotify, useRedirect, Button } from 'react-admin';

const ApproveButton = ({ record }) => {
    const notify = useNotify();
    const redirect = useRedirect();
    const [approve, { loading }] = useMutation(
        {
            type: 'update',
            resource: 'comments',
            payload: { id: record.id, data: { isApproved: true } },
        },
        {
            onSuccess: ({ data }) => {
                redirect('/comments');
                notify('Comment approved');
            },
            onFailure: (error) => notify(`Comment approval error: ${error.message}`, 'warning'),
        }
    );
    return <Button label="Approve" onClick={approve} disabled={loading} />;
```